# Wso2 Scim user update with Patch

Tags: wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

While trying to update a user through Scim Patch request i get an error and i am not sure what is the issue.

This is the request

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin -X PATCH -d '{
        "schemas": ["urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"],
            "name": {
                    "familyName": "Tester"
                },
          "meta": {
          }
}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/user-id-here
```

and this is the error in Wso2

```
ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service() for servlet [SCIMServlet] in context with path [/wso2] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:336)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:72)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:170)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:136)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.charon.core.protocol.endpoints.UserResourceEndpoint.updateWithPATCH(UserResourceEndpoint.java:622)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.resources.UserResource.updateUserPATCH(UserResource.java:307)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
    ... 47 more
```

I did the request as per Scim [doc](http://www.simplecloud.info/specs/draft-scim-api-01.html#edit-resource-with-patch)

There is a similar ticket at the Wso2 [issue tracker](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4184) but its consider as fixed.

Not sure what is the issue. Is it a problem in the request or some Wso2 configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems in your patch request.

1. userName attribute is missing. The WSO2 implementation requires you to have userName attribute when doing a PATCH operation on the user.
2. The "meta" attribute doesn't have a "attributes" sub attribute. This is  a spec violation. If you don't have any attributes to remove you can basically omit the meta attribute completely.
3. Specifying the schema ""urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0" seems to be creating an issue in the WSO2 Identity Server implementation.

The following is a working version of the curl command you have used.

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin -X PATCH -d "{
"schemas":[],
"name":{
  "familyName": "Tester"
},
"userName":"indunil",
"meta": {
  "attributes":[]
 }
}"
 --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/e9e57b58-3e90-4165-aadc-697a06f1eb9e
```

Comment: After changing the request i got a `[LDAP: error code 19 - entryUUID: no user modification allowed]` which was just because `entryUUID` is an operational field i guess. So i changed the id to some other column and it worked